# how to display image with Content-Type: image - php

Tags: php

i created function that get URL of image, and return compressed encoded image.
its work fine like that:

```
function compress($src)
{
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);  
    // Begin capturing the byte stream
    ob_start();

    // generate the byte stream
    imagejpeg($img, NULL, 60);
    $rawImageBytes = ob_get_clean();

    return base64_encode($rawImageBytes);
}



   echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . compress("https://media.petnet.co.il/ckFiles/images/kanaani.jpg") . "' />";
```

but i want to display the image with header('Content-Type: image/jpg');

how can i do that?

thanks.

Comment: is PHP function [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) what are you looking for?

Comment: yes, but i dont know how to display base64 image with header('Content-Type: image/jpg')

Comment: Your base64 data URL already stated that it is a JPEG ("data:image/jpeg"). Since it a data URI and not an HTTP response, it has no HTTP header. There is no place for you to put header in.

Comment: Note: Your PHP returns an HTML that contains an image tag. The PHP itself should have a "text/html" content type header, not "image/jpeg" (in case you're confused).

Comment: You would need to put this into a stand-alone script, that outputs _nothing but_ the binary image data. Send the header, followed by the image data - without encoding that as base64 first.

Comment: But doing this on-the-fly every time is not a good idea to begin with - image manipulation is a costly process. So you should probably cache the low-quality versions somewhere, if you need them more than once. (And making an HTTP request to fetch the original every single time would not be a good idea either.)

Answer (score 0):

In case you need the script returns compressed image only, try this

```
$image_data = compress("https://media.petnet.co.il/ckFiles/images/kanaani.jpg");
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
// or header("Content-type: image/jpg");
echo base64_decode($image_data);
```

instead of

```php
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . compress("...images/kanaani.jpg") . "' />";
```